# When affine variety is complete?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to prove that an affine variety $X$is complete only if $\dim X=0$? It is clear that in this case $X$ must be a single point. But I don't known why its dimension should be zero. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

If an affine variety $X\subset \mathbb A^n_k$ has more than one point (which is certainly the case if  $dim (X)\gt 0$) some coordinate function  $x_i$ is not constant on $X$ and we thus get a non constant regular function $x_i\in \mathcal O(X)\setminus k$.
On the other hand,  every regular function on a complete variety $Y$ *is* constant (in other words $\mathcal O(Y)= k$) and thus our positive-dimensional affine variety $X$ cannot be complete.

**Edit**
In the above answer, set in an elementary context not assuming schemes,  I Assumed $X$ irreducible and $k$ algebraically closed.
At a more advanced level one can only say that $\operatorname {dim} _k \Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X) \lt \infty $ for a scheme $X$ proper over a ( maybe not algebraically closed) arbitrary field $k$  . Thanks to @Alex for his comment which caused  this edit.

Comment: Original post was about complete varieties, but it is also true that the only regular functions on complete varieties are constant, so your argument answer the original post as well.

Comment: Dear @Callus, you are absolutely right and I corrected my answer. Since the question was probably written by a beginner in algebraic geometry (welcome to this enchanted world, yang!),  I guess that I subconsciously substituted "projective" in place of "complete". Anyway, thanks a lot for your attentive reading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I still can't understand why every regular function on a complete variety is constant. I only know that "complete" means that the corresponding projection morphism is  closed. So could you give me some more details? Thank you!

Comment: @yang Think about a regular function as a morphism to $\mathbb{A}^1$. If your variety is irreducible (which you certainly can assume for this problem) then the image is closed (since your variety is complete), and irreducible and so must either be a point or all of $\mathbb{A}^1$. But, $\mathbb{A}^1$ is certainly not complete (and the image of complete varieties are complete) since there are tons of non-closed projections.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I feel a little silly asking this, but could you clarify something? When someone says "regular function", what precisely do they mean? If one defines a variety over $k$ to be a reduced finite type separated scheme over $\text{Spec}(k)$, and by regular function they mean "global section", then I don't understand the statement that all regular functions on a complete variety are constant (despite my previous comment :]). For example, $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C})\to\text{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$ is proper, but the global sections of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}))$ isn't $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Alex, I  assumed that the question was from a relative beginner in algebraic geometry and I tried to answer it at that level. In other words  I interpreted "affine variety" as  "irreducible closed subset of affine space over an algebraically closed field" in the style of, say, Fulton's book on algebraic curves. At a more advanced level you can only say that for a  scheme $X$ proper over a field $k$, the $k$-vector space $\Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X)$ is finite-dimensional, as is $\Gamma(X, \mathcal F_X)$ for any coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$. Your example beautifully illustrates this.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Of course, that makes sense. I just wanted to make sure I was making the terminology connection. Thank!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand properly you are asking why an affine variety which is a single point has dimension zero?

It is very clear from the definition of dimension: A variety X has dimension n is there exists an chain of irreducible closed subsets of X $Z_0 \subsetneq Z_1\subsetneq...\subsetneq Z_n \subsetneq X$.

If X has to have dimension 1 then  u need at least  two points because you need two irreducible closed subsets of  X one containing the other properly.